# CKeditor, retrieve user text from database

Tags: php, sql, ckeditor

Currently I'm busy with a simple CKeditor notepad for webapplication. I already have code to save the user text into the database.

Now I want to add code that will retrieve the latest saved (latest id) text from the database, so the user can continue his/her work.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['editor1'])) {
        $text = $_POST['editor1'];

        $conn = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$db") or die("ERROR");

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO content (content) VALUES ('$text')");

        if($query)
            echo "Succes!";
        else
            echo "Failed!"; 
    }
?>
```

this is the code to save the users text.

Now I want to build code that will retrieve the latest saved text from the database, but I can't make a start with my code.

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">

    <?php 
        $conn = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$db") or die("ERROR");

        $sql = "SELECT content from content";           
    ?>

</textarea>
```

This is what I currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute your query by using [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and also need to fetch data by using [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) as:

**Example:**

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `content` FROM `content`";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $result['content']; // will print your content.
?>
</textarea>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

For fetching latest record than you can use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT 1` in your query as:

```
$sql = "SELECT `content` FROM `content` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"; // assuming id is your primary key column.
```

Comment: Hey! Now the text in the textarea is the first id from my database, only I want to display the latest id that is saved in the database.

Comment: @SmashingJummy: use `ORDER BY id DESC`